# symfony 1.4 resett values from fields after fail

Tags: forms, symfony1, action, field, reset

How can i reset my formfield values ?

```
action:
            $this->form = new $class();
            $this->form->bind($request->getParameter('signin'));
            if ($this->form->isValid())
            {
                $values = $this->form->getValues();
                            $this->redirect('@example');
                    }
            else
            {
                if ($this->form->hasGlobalErrors())
                    $this->errorclass = 'error';
            }
            $this->form->resetFormFields();
            return $this->renderPartial('ajax/example);
```

I have 2 fields email and pw: want to resett them after error that they empty

This dont work :(

```
$this->form->resetFormFields();
```

Any solutions?
Thx in regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your form has only 2 fields (email and pw), you can simply reinit form.

```
else
{
  if ($this->form->hasGlobalErrors())
    $this->errorclass = 'error';
  $this->form = new $class();
}
```

If your form has more fields (no only email and pw) and you want to preserve other field values, you can remove email and pw values and bind new form.

```
$values = $request->getParameter('signin');
$this->form->bind($values);
if ($this->form->isValid())
{
  $this->redirect('@example');
}
else
{
  if ($this->form->hasGlobalErrors())
    $this->errorclass = 'error';
  $values['pw'] = '';
  $values['email'] = '';
  $this->form = new $class();
  $this->form->bind($values);
}
```